# Getting [Guzzle\Http\Exception\RequestException] Error completing request

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel, laravel-4, guzzle

I wrote a simple script to download some .JPG files and reupload them to Amazon S3.  It works almost every time but every once in a while I'm getting the error:

```
[Guzzle\Http\Exception\RequestException]
Error completing request
```

Since the error doesn't tell me much, where would I find more information as to what is causing the error.  I don't even know if it is in the downloading of my files from the FTP server, the renaming, or the uploading to S3.  Very confused on this error.

**EDIT**

Following the advice below, I added in the catch portion but I'm not sure what that's telling me exactly.  This script is downloading jpg's and then uploading them to Amazon S3.  Here's what the Catch is providing:

```
#0 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(378): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->processResponse(Array)
#1 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/EntityEnclosingRequest.php(49): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->setState('complete', Array)
#2 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(286): Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest->setState('complete', Array)
#3 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(244): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array)
#4 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(227): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages()
#5 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(211): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->executeHandles()
#6 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(105): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->perform()
#7 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiProxy.php(91): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->send()
#8 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(282): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy->send()
#9 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(284): Guzzle\Http\Client->send(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest))
#10 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(136): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->send(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest))
#11 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php(153): Guzzle\Service\Client->execute(Object(Aws\S3\Command\S3Command))
#12 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php(189): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->execute()
#13 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(76): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->getResult()
#14 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(105): Guzzle\Service\Client->__call('PutObject', Array)
#15 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/app/commands/ProcessListings.php(156): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->__call('putObject', Array)
#16 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/app/commands/ProcessListings.php(156): Aws\S3\S3Client->putObject(Array)
#17 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/app/commands/ProcessListings.php(137): ProcessListings->UploadImageToS3('naples', '213506540', '213506540-naple...', 'app/processing/...')
#18 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/app/commands/ProcessListings.php(72): ProcessListings->DownloadImages('naples', '213506540', 'http://extimage...', '213506540-naple...', 12)
#19 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(108): ProcessListings->fire()
#20 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(244): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(898): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(191): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(ProcessListings), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /Volumes/Data/Users/chrisfarrugia/Sites/listingnaples.com/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#26 {main}
```

Comment: Amazon's API use's Guzzle internally, so it's probably that. Try wrapping your amazon calls in a try / catch and see if it tells you where the issue arises.

Comment: `Catch( \Exception $e ){ echo $e->getTraceAsString(); }` should do it. setting \Exception will catch any exceptions that extend it (which should be all exceptions).

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? I'm getting the same exception...